# How do I render options and optgroups conditionally with v-for?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a data structured like this

```js
const options = [
    {
        group: 'Fruits', options: [
            { label: 'Apple', value: 'f-1' },
            { label: 'Banana', value: 'f-2' },
            { label: 'Orange', value: 'f-3' },
        ],
    },
    { label: 'Chocolate', value: 'm-1' },
    { label: 'Cake', value: 'm-2' },
    {
        group: 'Vegetables', options: [
            { label: 'Cabbage', value: 'v-1' },
            { label: 'Tomato', value: 'v-2' },
        ],
    },
    { label: 'Puddin', value: 'm-3' },
]
```

I would like to render it into a `select` component like this:

```html
<select>
    <optgroup label="Fruits">
        <option value="f-1">Apple</option>
        <option value="f-2">Banana</option>
        <option value="f-3">Orange</option>
    </optgroup>
    <option value="m-1">Chocolate</option>
    <option value="m-2">Cake</option>
    <optgroup label="Vegetables">
        <option value="v-1">Cabbage</option>
        <option value="v-2">Tomato</option>
    </optgroup>
    <option value="m-3">Pudding</option>
</select>
```

I tried something like this but it gave me an error:

```html
<select>
    <optgroup v-for="group in options" v-if="group.group" :label="group.group" :key="group.group">
        <option v-for="option in group" :key="option.value" :value="option.value">{{ option.label }}</option>
    </optgroup>
    <option v-for="option in options" v-if="!option.group" :key="option.value" :value="option.value">{{ option.label }}</option>
</select>
```

> The 'options' variable inside 'v-for' directive should be replaced with a computed property that returns filtered array instead. You should not mix 'v-for' with 'v-if'

Any ideas on how should I render it correctly? I'm kinda struggling with this for a while, thanks in advance!

Comment: use a computed property (call it say, `optionsgroups`) that filters options with group property and use that in your v-for instead of options, i.e `v-for="group in optonsgroups"` - with no v-if required now - though, the order may be wrong then

Comment: @JaromandaX I thought about using a computed property too but mixing the grouped and non-grouped options seemed impossible

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is where the [non-rendering `<template>` tag](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html#Conditional-Groups-with-v-if-on-lt-template-gt) comes in handy

```js
const options = [{"group":"Fruits","options":[{"label":"Apple","value":"f-1"},{"label":"Banana","value":"f-2"},{"label":"Orange","value":"f-3"}]},{"label":"Chocolate","value":"m-1"},{"label":"Cake","value":"m-2"},{"group":"Vegetables","options":[{"label":"Cabbage","value":"v-1"},{"label":"Tomato","value":"v-2"}]},{"label":"Puddin","value":"m-3"}]

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: () => ({ options, selected: null })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <select v-model="selected">
    <template v-for="option in options">
      <!-- if the `group` property is truthy -->
      <optgroup v-if="option.group" :label="option.group" :key="option.group">
        <option v-for="opt in option.options" :value="opt" :key="opt.value">
          {{ opt.label }}
        </option>
      </optgroup>
      <!-- otherwise -->
      <option v-else :value="option" :key="option.value">
        {{ option.label }}
      </option>
    </template>
  </select>
  
  <pre>selected = {{ selected }}</pre>
</div>
```

Note that you cannot put `key` attributes on `<template>` so those should go where appropriate on the elements within.

In the example above, I've also bound the entire option object instead of just the `value` but you can choose the best value to bind for your usage.

Comment: Wow I didn't even know there's a none rendering element in vue, I was hoping there's something similar to `<></>` from reactjs. Thank you so much!